# SQL Server error: 26 in MVC3 Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 web application (C# .Net V4) that accesses a number of different databases within the same SQL Server 2008R2 SQLEXPRESS instance. The databases provide a degree of separation between schema's and datasets and, in the case of two of them, are shared within other web applications.

I am encountering an old favourite SQL Server error...

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My problem is that this is not occurring consistently for all the connections defined in the application. By that I mean that each database on the server is accessed by a different connecting in the web.config file as follows:-

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Elmah.Sql"                    connectionString="Data Source=EMEA-CAT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=elmah;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="fs_utilitiesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=EMEA-CAT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fs_utilities;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="quartzConnectionString"       connectionString="Data Source=EMEA-CAT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=quartz;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="pdmsConnectionString"         connectionString="Data Source=EMEA-CAT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=pdms;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The all point to the same server instance and three out of the four work without issue. However, any attempt to connect to the quartzConnectionString database results in the server error.

I have followed the normal recommendations for troubleshooting this common problem can find not specific issues. Such as those listed in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

I can connect to the server instace using SSMSE and SQLCMD without any problem using TCP and named pipes. The SQL Browser is running on the server and I ran the PortQry command and it indicates that ports 1433 and 1434 are accessible.

The only difference for the database that fails is that is is running at a SQL Server 2005 compatability level to be able to work with Quartz.NET.

Comment: Do you have any other instances of SQL Server running?

Comment: You might be able to get more answers at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com), if you'd like us to migrate this for you, please flag your question and let us know.

Comment: Does the user that is utilising these connections have the required access to destination server and all of the databases? If so, is this also true for the target environment (ie. TEST/PROD)?

Comment: @SBlacker, no this is the only instance SQL Server instance on the host.

Comment: @MrMoose - Yes the user has the correct access to the destination server, its actually common to all four connection. Sounds like something I need to explore though as this error only occurs in the production environment not dev or test. It's not affecting production users as the connection is only use by the an admin to administer schedule tasks - something that can currently be manually worked around using "raw" SQL rather than a pretty GUI.

Comment: I think that given it is localised to your production environment, and one user in particular, it is worthwhile focusing your attention on that environment specifically. Maybe try isolate the issue by creating a small dummy app and attaching to the affected database using the credentials that are causing you issues.